# Error : The publisher could not be verified

Tags: c#, c++, .net, vb.net, windows

My application runs on startup. However, I always get this message,

[image]

Other than certificate, is there any method to prevent that ?

What I have done, I did vbs and run the application from that vbs, still without any luck.

```
set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
appDataLocation = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%APPDATA%")
WshShell.Run Chr(34) & appDataLocation & "\File.exe" & Chr(34), 0
set WshShell = Nothing
```

Comment: Have you ever tried unchecking that checkbox?

Comment: Funny reply. No comment.

Comment: So... you want to programmatically disable the warning dialog that the OS displays when launching unsigned programs... without signing your program?  Do you understand why this dialog exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, without Administrative privileges its kind hard to disable this "annoying" message, Unless of course you use an 'illegal' or 'bad' method.

Besides, why would you like to do that? if you are creating some kind of malware, you're clearly need to re-think the whole thing.

But I'll give you a tiny 'of the record' hint: disabling Windows' UAC and other nice and protecting services (which will require a one-time Admin access, of course), will help you solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, but I just achieved my goal by adding some registry values.